# Mongdb uninstall (and install) failures: Already uninstalled or something broken?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, uninstall, mongodb

I tried to install MongoDB, but something went wrong with the installation and I want to install it again. Unfortunately, I get errors when attempting to remove/pruge, and I suspect those errors might be related to my subsequent failures to reinstall.

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge mongo*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mongodb18-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo20-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo18-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-stable' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-server-core' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-enterprise' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-nightly' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo18-10gen-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo20-10gen-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-dev' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-enterprise' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-clients' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-enterprise-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-server' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongo-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb20-10gen' for glob 'mongo*'
Package 'mongo-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-enterprise' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-enterprise-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-enterprise-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-10gen-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo18-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo18-10gen-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo20-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo20-10gen-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-enterprise' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-enterprise-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-nightly' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-stable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb18-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb20-10gen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongo-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-server-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-enterprise-tools' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org* mongodb-org-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
After this operation, 62.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also tried reinstall:

```
~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5
  mongo-tools mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-server-core
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5
  mongo-tools mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-server-core
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 1 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 154 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libboost-program-options1.65.1 amd64 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 [137 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libtcmalloc-minimal4 amd64 2.5-2.2ubuntu3 [91.6 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgoogle-perftools4 amd64 2.5-2.2ubuntu3 [190 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcrecpp0v5 amd64 2:8.39-9 [15.3 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 amd64 0.5.2-4ubuntu1 [150 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mongo-tools amd64 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 [12.3 MB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mongodb-clients amd64 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 [20.2 MB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mongodb-server-core amd64 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 [20.3 MB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mongodb-server all 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 [12.6 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mongodb amd64 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 [9,892 B]
Fetched 53.4 MB in 5s (11.3 MB/s)    
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and autoremove:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

I am confused is it already fully removed and that's why I am getting these errors, or is it failing to remove? If so, then how is dpkg coming up with the number 62.2 Mb to be removed? Would I be better of nuking my entire Ubuntu installation and starting fromm scratch? Is there a good, COMPLETE guide to installing MongoDB on Ubuntu 18.04? Because even to get my previous broken install partly looking, I had to do stuff suggested in threads that was not mentioned in the official install guide.

Edit: to be clear the issue is that I CANNOT apt-get purge mongo, and the service isn't even running.

```
~$  sudo service mongod stop
[sudo] password for james: 
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
~$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-server' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Package 'mongodb-org-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org* mongodb-org-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
After this operation, 62.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

force remove didn't work either:

```
~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
~$ sudo apt-get --force-yes remove  mongodb-org-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
After this operation, 62.2 MB disk space will be freed.
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
~$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all  mongodb-org-server
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--purge):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
```

Comment: Wildcards (*) in apt commands is generally considered unwise. You may get unexpected and catastrophic results. It only takes a moment to find the correct package name.

Comment: That makes sense, but my system seems fine. Do you think that could be the cause of this? And should I consider the fact that the official documentation recommends using a wildcard a sign that the official documentation sucks?

Comment: Your problem seems to be the pre-removal script. Either edit the script so it doesn't fail, or use apt's --force flag so apt continues the uninstall anyway.

Comment: force didn't work, guess I'll have to look into editing the script. Or more just install from the Ubuntu repo against the recommendation of the mongo manual.
*Wait nope, cant install from ubuntu repo because of whatever is still hanging around from before.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there were some mongdb related files hanging around in /var/lib/dpkg/info that, once deleted, allowed purge to complete successfully. 
I am pretty mad at the mongoDB documentation for advising that their package was better maintained than the OS repositories and that I should install from their repository.